# MVC общие действия для всех контроллеров

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Есть приложение ASP.NET MVC 5. Есть ряд контроллеров. Так вот, мне нужно для каждого контроллера сделать ряд повторяющихся действий. Как?

Я уверен, что попросят конкретики (хотя не уверен, что это необходимо), поэтому расскажу про действия.

Если пользователь запросил такой URL: http://my.app/Controller/Page/?qwe=asd , то определенные переменные (не все, но вот в данном случае qwe точно) должны записаться в куках, и далее должна идти переадресация на чистый URL: http://my.app/Controller/Page

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Варианты:

```
1. HttpApplication.BeginRequest
```

В `Global.asax.cs` заводите метод

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) { }
```

который будет вызываться ASP.Net-ом в начале обработки каждого запроса.

```
2. ActionFilterAttribute.OnActionExecuting
```

Пишите наследника `ActionFilterAttribute`, в нем переписываете виртуальный метод `OnActionExecuting`, где когда надо назначаете `filterContext.Result`. Украшаете этим атрибутом Ваши контроллеры.

```
3. Controller.OnActionExecuting
```

Заводите базовый класс для Ваших контроллеров, в его переписанном методе `OnActionExecuting` анализируете необходимость редиректа текущего запроса.

Comment: А можно подробнее? С `Controller.OnActionExecuting` все понятно, а вот с двумя другими... В каком месте их нужно использовать?

Comment: @IRumba Подробнее про второй вариант тут: https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/8.1.php

Answer (score 0):

Можно модуль написать, думаю как раз для подобных дел они и предназначены

```
public class RedirectModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
    }

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest += HandleRequest;
    }
    public void HandleRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var req = HttpContext.Current.Request;
        var existingParams = new List<string>
        {
            "qwe"
            //Ну и остальные параметры
        };
        foreach(var param in existingParams)
        {
            if(req.QueryString[param] != null)
            {
                var cookies = new HttpCookie("MyCookies");
                cookies[param] = req.QueryString[param];
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("нужный редирект");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: а что дальше делать с модулем с этим?

Comment: @iRumba находишь в web.config system.webServer->modules, туда добавляешь имя и тип модуля, погуглить можно во всяком случае